# TypeORM relations in transaction

Tags: typeorm

After reading TypeORM documentation, it is not clear to me, if it is safe to use lazy relations inside transactions. The [documentation about transactions](https://typeorm.io/transactions#creating-and-using-transactions) says:

> All operations MUST be executed using the provided transactional entity manager.

Does it apply for loading related entities as well? When using lazy relations, can I do the following?

```
await dataSource.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
    const parentEntity = await transactionalEntityManager.findOneBy(ParentEntity, {
        id: 1,
    });

    const childEntity = await parentEntity.child; // It works, but is it safe?
})
```

If not, what is the proper way of loading relations inside transactions? Thank you.